# React use setTimeout to setState in componentDidiUpdate to make a position transition is slow

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, settimeout

I was creating a component with multiple inline names in a block, and if the block is too long to be bigger than it's container in the DOM, then switch to animation mode, move the names block to left 1px per 20ms, when the last char of last name disappears in the left edge of the container, show the first char in the right edge of container and loop again infinitely.

If it is a JQuery project, I'll try manipulating DOM, but it is React, so I gave the names block a style to represent the position, and give the component a state named style, then check out whether the line's width is wider than it's parent's width, if true, update the style state with left = left - 1, let react do the update.

code sample: https://codepen.io/Fadeoc/pen/PKZvQp

```
class People extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      style: null
    };
    this.scrollToLeft = this.scrollToLeft.bind(this);
    this.scrollingLeftTimeoutFn = this.scrollingLeftTimeoutFn.bind(this);
  }

  scrollingLeftTimeoutFn() {
    if (this.offsetX + this.totalNameWidth > 0) {
      this.offsetX -= 1;
      this.setState({
        style: {left: this.offsetX + "px"}
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        style: {left: this.containerWidth + "px"}
      });
      this.offsetX = this.containerWidth;
    }
  }

  scrollToLeft() {
    if (Object.keys(this.peopleRef).length > 0) {
      this.containerWidth = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.div).getBoundingClientRect().width;
      this.totalNameWidth = Object.keys(this.peopleRef).reduce((sumWidth, key) => {
        return sumWidth + ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.peopleRef[key]).getBoundingClientRect().width; + 40;
      }, 0);
      if (this.totalNameWidth > this.containerWidth) {
        this.scrollingLeftTimeout = setTimeout(this.scrollingLeftTimeoutFn, 20);
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.offsetX = 0;
    this.scrollToLeft()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.scrollingLeftTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.scrollingLeftTimeout);
    }
    this.scrollToLeft();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.scrollingLeftTimeout) {
      clearTimeout(this.scrollingLeftTimeout);
    }
  }

  render() {
    //it is not necessary to create array here, but in the real project, it has to, so keep it in case this would be the reason of heavy performance
    let arr = ['stanford slander', 'josh snow', 'drago drakaleis'];
    //it is not necessary to create ref object here, but in the real project, it has to, so keep it in case this would be the reason of heavy performance
    this.peopleRef = {};
    let peopleList = arr.map((people, i) => <li ref={li => this.peopleRef[`${i}`] = li} key={i} className="people">{people}</li>);
    return (
      <div ref={div => this.div = div} className="container">
        <ul className="mask" style={this.state.style}>
          {peopleList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <People />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It works, but as what I am afraid, the performance is not good.

1. when scrolling mouse wheel on the page the timer becomes slow also the animation, it is not obvious in this example, but it does, and very obvious on a page with about 20 instance of this component.
2. Leave the page there a while, then focus back on the page with mouse clicking, there will be a loading circle in the right-top corner of the mouse pointer, like Chrome is doing GC.
3. Open the console, navigate to the list item, click node there, switch to another forth and back, the animation will be slower, again, not obvious but it does on this example, very bad on the real project.
4. Even I use a react state updating way to achieve this, but somehow, it is also kind of DOM manipulation as I query for the width every time in case there is a new name push from the websocket server. I am not feeling right about this.

To be honest, I d met this problem in my last project, at that time, the team leader couldn't tell the reason either. Today, I googled it whole day long, and only thing I found is useful is to abstract the function expression from inside the setTimeout to outside, to prevent evaluate it everytime, and that became scrollingLeftTimeoutFn.

I don't think this is a only React-app bad coding performance problem, but also a general bad coding performance problem because in the last project I use none library.

I am pretty sure it is due to setTimeout, this picture below is chrome performance tool in about 50000ms long, the Timer Fired occupied almost 80% of the busy part, which occupy 40% - 60% of the whole period, and the idle part is only 60% - 40%:

[image]

By the way, I know React-transition-group, but prefer not to use it, is there any way else to do this in React?

More importantly, why and how to resolve this setTimeout performance problem?

Thank you.

Comment: `setState` is async and react will sometime batch `setStates` called within a close interval of each other. So I'd assume it'd be almost impossible to have a smooth animation with this. Have you tried it with ref and conventional DOM manipulation? Is there still a performance issue?  Personally, I haven't had any trouble with getting a smooth animation with vanilla javascript.

Comment: @squgeim thanks for the batch updating information, I tried use setTimeout and manipulate DOM  only without state updating, it sure also works, about the smooth, I think they are the same. But as you can see, timer fired occupied almost 80% of the time, I do not think this is right.

Comment: I see you are offsetting by 1px. That's too little. The minimum time for `setTimeout` is `10ms`. So the offset should be the number of pixels that need to move each 10ms to get to the final value in a given time. For example if you need to move 200px in 200ms, the offset needs to be 10px, and timeout is 10ms.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But that is almost the fastest speed I can accept, I prefer 1px / 40ms more. but 10px / 400ms will look like the character is jumping forward.

Comment: The total time includes all code invoked from within setTimeout, and all the tasks performed by the browser like updating layout, painting etc. Scroll the flamechart down and look at GPU chart: maybe you're hitting its limits. On my PC the codepen demo uses less than 10% of CPU time https://puu.sh/xhuY4/4d9ab7d2cc.png

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for your reply, I checked GPU usage, there are plenty available, I do not think that is the reason. Thank you for this perspective anyway.